# Images are not loading on the live website

Tags: api, imdb

I have created a website http://moviesnight.club using [THIS API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) everything is working fine on localhost, but when I have uploaded it into hosting the movie posters are being loaded and error on console [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)]. But all other thing are ok. So is there any suggestion how to make it work?

**This is how it looks on HOSTING (moviesnight.club)**

[image: This is how it looks on HOSTING (moviesnight.club)]

**This is how it looks on localhost**

[image: This is how it looks on localhost]

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding an api key to your request

From the OMDb website usage this is what your url needs to be

```
http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&
```

The website also provides this link to obtain your api key

http://beforethecode.com/projects/omdb/apikey.aspx